# Map List<List<string>> into List<Dictionary<string, int>>

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm trying the following code to map a list of lists into list of dictionaries but I'm getting error

> index out of range

Updated the question

```
List<List<string>> _terms = new List<List<string>>();
for (int i = 0; i < _numcats; ++i)
{
    _terms.Add( GenerateTerms(_docs[i]));
}
// where _docs[i] is an array element 
// and the procedure GenerateTerms returns list  

int j = 0;
foreach (List <string> catterms in _terms)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < catterms.Count; i++)
    {
        _wordsIndex[j].Add(catterms[i], i);
    }
    j ++;            
}
```

Could any help please?

Comment: Most likely `_wordsIndex[j]` is not available. Can you share your code where you are initializing `_wordsIndex`?

Comment: @ Sinngh.. I have updated the question and I'm sure that the list is available

Comment: @Qaesar - That's where you initialize _terms, but what about _wordsIndex, which is where the problem likely lies.

Comment: @ Sinngh.the first loop work well, and I get list of list fulled by items. but the second loop give the mentioned error

Comment: @Qaesar The explicit loops are unnecessary. See JerKimball's and my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- `_terms` is type `List<List<string>>`
- `_wordsIndex` is type `List<Dictionary<string,int>>`

Try this:

```
var _wordsIndex = 
    _terms.Select(listOfWords => 
        // for each list of words
        listOfWords
            // each word => pair of (word, index)
            .Select((word, wordIndex) => 
                   new KeyValuePair<string,int>(word, wordIndex))
            // to dictionary these
            .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value))
        // Finally, ToList the resulting dictionaries
        .ToList();
```

A note of caution, however - and this bug exists in your example code as well: Calling `Add` on a dictionary where that key already exists is a no-no. To ensure safety here, you'd probably want to get a `Distinct()` on the key value pairs.

Comment: The KVP bit is clever, I should have thought of that. +1

Comment: Hah - looks like you beat me by about a minute; didn't notice the "new answer posted" banner. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming _wordsIndex is the `List<Dictionary<string, int>>`. If so, you're probably trying to access an item that hasn't been added yet. So you'll need to change it to something like this:

```
foreach (List <string> catterms in _terms)
{
    var newDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < catterms.Count; i++)
    {
        newDict.Add(catterms[i], i);
    }
    _wordsIndex.Add(newDict)
}
```

Notice that a dictionary is created before the inner loop, gets populated inside the inner loop, then added to the main list after the inner loop concludes.